# HTML: Scroll line by line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an unordered list with a variable number of list items. The `<ul>` is of fixed height (actually the height of a single line of text) and set to `overflow-y: scroll`.

When I scroll the mouse-wheel, a certain vertical distance is traversed. I would like to have it exatly scroll line by line, to ensure that a `<li>` is always properly centered in the visible part of the `<ul>`.

Wrong behaviour:
[image]

```css
:root {
  --default-line-height: 24px;
}

.myUl {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: var(--default-line-height);
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.myLi {
  font-size: var(--default-line-height);
}
```

```html
<ul class="myUl">
  <li class="myLi">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
  <li class="myLi">Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</li>
  <li class="myLi">Cum sociis natoque penatibus</li>
  <li class="myLi">Donec quam felis, ultricies nec</li>
  <li class="myLi">Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</li>
  <li class="myLi">Donec pede justo, fringilla vel</li>
  <li class="myLi">In enim justo, rhoncus ut</li>
</ul>

<p>Please scroll the blue area.</p>
```

---

I played with scroll-snap but to no real success. The animation "feels" awkward and it still scrolls multiple lines. I could probably build something with [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll) but that seems unnecessarily cumbersome.

It seemed reasonable to be able to scroll line by line under certain conditions. List-like-controls (eg dropdowns) show this behaviour in many frameworks. I would not have thought this would need more than some clever css...

---

**Update:**
[Feroz’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70155093/1054981) below only solves the snapping aspect of the problem. It is still possible to scroll multiple lines in one go.

Comment: "*[It] feels awkward*" That's probably because it's awful UX to modify default scrolling behavior in the first place, as you're forcing your users to cede control of how they want to be viewing your content in the first place. It's generally never a good idea to deviate from established norms like this without a particularly stellar reason for doing so.

Comment: @esqew Absolutely true! BUT I try to output some kind of log. Having the list items being out of center isn't a particular good user experience either.

Answer (score 3):

Please check my snippet. Now you can scroll line by line.

```css
:root {
  --default-line-height: 28px;
}

.myUl {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: var(--default-line-height);
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.myLi {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: var(--default-line-height);
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  scroll-snap-stop: normal;
}
```

```html
<ul class="myUl">
  <li class="myLi">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
  <li class="myLi">Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</li>
  <li class="myLi">Cum sociis natoque penatibus</li>
  <li class="myLi">Donec quam felis, ultricies nec</li>
  <li class="myLi">Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</li>
  <li class="myLi">Donec pede justo, fringilla vel</li>
  <li class="myLi">In enim justo, rhoncus ut</li>
</ul>

<p>Please scroll the blue area.</p>
```

Comment: Sidenote: this might not work if you scroll with your mousewheel since that depends on your scroll settings (speed, amount of lines etc.)

Comment: It is working for me here. Not sure why not working for you.

Comment: @Reyno It's working fine here.

Comment: @Feroz That was quick. I feel very stupid now :)  
 Is it possible, to finetune that little animation? The mdn article is a bit vague: "Specifying any precise animations or physics used to enforce those snap points is not covered by this property but instead left up to the user agent."

Comment: @cl10k What you've quoted isn't vague at all; it's stating that it isn't something you can control with CSS, and that each browser will have it's own way of animating to the snap points.

Comment: Actually your approach only solves half of the problem. It still scrolls a couple of lines each time. Which probably is the default behaviour of the browser. Any ideas on how to bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution on https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/

```
<div class="container">
  <section class="child"></section>
  <section class="child"></section>
  <section class="child"></section>
  <p>...</p>
</div>

.container {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.child {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```